# Word for this military training excercise structure?

Tags: word-request

I was watching a movie a few days ago, the movie was a military themed movie.

There was a scene in the movie, where a group of recruits were doing training excercise.

The training framework/panel/structure was complicated and elaborate. It consist of crawling activity, swinging, climbing etc.

I have seen such structures in other skill based contests tv shows, where contestants are supposed to perform the above mentioned activities.

What word would describe such elaborate strucutre--maze?

Answer (score 4):

The term that you are looking for is "assault course". Here is the definition from the [Cambridge DIctionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assault-course):

> an area of land on which soldiers have to run between and climb over or cross various objects, designed to test their strength and physical condition

There is also a more general term "obstacle course" which the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obstacle-course) defines as:

> a race in which runners have to climb over, under, or through a series of obstacles

As you can see, this term is not specifically about military training: It could be used about an event at a children's party, or about a fun activity for adults at an informal sporting event, and I have also seen it used about something created for [squirrels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMtn25zxT10).

Comment: I did a little bit of research after posting. Obstacle course conveys the same message.

Comment: Not qulte.  An obstacle course is usually intended to be a fun activity, for children.  An assault course is a challenging and demanding course, to test the soldier's condition.

Comment: Certainly, the meaning of "obstacle course" has been expanded to refer to a children's activity. [The comprehensive description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstacle_course#Military) at Wikipedia *begins* with the military usage.